# Vue html elements not showing correct output

Tags: vue.js

I am following microsoft online Vue tuturial. But following code should be outputting as below html page:
[image]

But I am getting this as output not sure why.
Why `productName` and `productDescription` are not appearing as string values?
[image]
index.js:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            productName: 'Book a Cruise to the Moon',
            productDescription: 'Cruise to the moon in our luxurious shuttle. Watch the astronauts working outside the International Space Station.',
            // additional properties later


        };
    },
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Relecloud Galaxy Tours</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/styles.css" />
    <!-- TODO: Import Vue.js core library -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav-bar"></div>
    <h1>Relecloud Galaxy Tours</h1>

    <!-- TODO: Add information display -->
    <div id="app">
        <h2>{{ productName }}</h2>
        <div>{{ productDescription }}</div>
    </div>

    
    <!-- TODO: Import Vue app -->
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <script>
        app.mount('#app');
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be using Vue2 or Vue3? It probably have updated to v3 through the CDN while your tutorial is based on Vue2.

Comment: Here is the proper CDN link to use for Vue2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/vue-get-started/ this is tutorial but they have not specified which version they are using for tutorial

Comment: Oh, the tutorial is for Vue3.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my computer and it worked for me.

Make sure the file path is correct and try again.

I just copied and pasted.

Comment: Code is working but productName and productDescription are not appearing as string values. Instead their variable names are appearing.

Comment: Get your code inside index.js and insert above app.mount("#app").